# non-deterministic crashing behavior in app w/ custom frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I am working on an app that uses 4 frameworks i made.  Its structured as a workspace and each framework has a project.  This one framework that basically encapsulates some UIKit convenience functions keeps on crashing at this call site.

`containerView.pinTo(superView: hostView)`.

what happens is I build and run the app once.  Then, for the second and remaining runs it crashes here.  So its non-deterministic in that it works once, but never again.  Here, both `hostView` and `containerView` are not nil.

When problems occur at this level (frameworks, linking, etc.) I don't even know where to begin.  I've embedded and linked the frameworks as best as I know.  What is happening here?